# Is there a way to extract package.json from package-lock.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, package-lock.json

I'm working on a project in which the package.json file is missing. The developer has pushed the package-lock.json file without the package.json file.

How can I create a clean package.json from the package-lock.json file in case it is at all possible?

Comment: You can't. package-lock.json doesn't contain all data from package.json. It contains dependency versions. Just ask a dev to submit package.json.

Comment: You could get the name and version and maybe figure out the dependencies and devDependencies, but that's not all that's in the package file - it likely also contains scripts and config for some of the packages you're using, for example.

Comment: @estus no one has access to him. that's why I'm trying to reverse engineer it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible to generate full `package.json` from `package-lock.json` because the latter doesn't contain all necessary data. It contains only a list of dependencies with specific versions without original semvers. Production and development dependencies are mixed up along with nested dependencies.

Fresh `package.json` could be generated, then augmented with these dependencies with something like:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const packageLock = require('./package-lock.json');
const package = require('./package.json');

package.dependencies = Object.entries(packageLock.dependencies)
.reduce((deps, [dep, { version }]) => Object.assign(deps, { [dep]: version }), {});

fs.writeFileSync('./package-new.json', JSON.stringify(package, null, 2));
```

Nested dependencies could be filtered out by checking `requires` key, but this can affect project's own dependencies.

Answer (score 6):

Simply run `npm init` and it will pull all of the current dependencies from `package-lock.json` if you already have `node_modules/` generated. If not, run `npm ci` to generate the node modules from the `package-lock.json` and then run `npm init` to generate the `package.json` file.

Comment: just creates a blank package file for me!

Comment: @asulaiman What version are you using? I just tested it again using `6.8.0` and it works dandy.

Comment: It doesn't actually generate `package.json` from `package-lock.json`, but from `node_modules`. If you don't have `node_modules`, you can run `npm ci` to generate `node_modules` from `package-lock.json` and then run `npm init` to generate a `package.json`.

Comment: @Stevula Good explanation! I'm updating the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly improved version of accepted answer script. Will pull locked versions out of the package-lock.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const packageLock = require('./package-lock.json');
const package = require('./package.json');

package.dependencies = Object.keys(package.dependencies)
.reduce((deps, dep) => Object.assign(deps, { [dep]: packageLock.dependencies[dep].version }), {});

package.devDependencies = Object.keys(package.devDependencies)
.reduce((deps, dep) => Object.assign(deps, { [dep]: packageLock.dependencies[dep].version }), {});

fs.writeFileSync('./package-new.json', JSON.stringify(package, null, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly improved version of improved version for newer versions of NPM:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const packageLock = require('./package-lock.json');
const package = require('./package.json');

const packageJsonNew = package;

// Refactor above code into a function
const updateDependencies = (dependencies, newDependencies) => {
    Object.keys(dependencies).forEach(dep => {
        try {
            console.log("✅ node_modules/" + dep + ": " + packageLock.packages["node_modules/" + dep].version);
            newDependencies[dep] = packageLock.packages["node_modules/" + dep].version;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("❌ node_modules/" + dep + ": " + error);
        }
    });
}

updateDependencies(package.dependencies, packageJsonNew.dependencies);
updateDependencies(package.devDependencies, packageJsonNew.devDependencies);

fs.writeFileSync('./package-new.json', JSON.stringify(packageJsonNew, null, 2));
```